# Android Activity with different "States"

Tags: android

I'm creating an Android application where in one of my activities has multiple view states/layout and those are:

- Link Device (shows a graphic with a button to open another activity)
- Connected (shows the main layout out of the activity)
- No Connection (shows a graphic and a text indicating there's no internet connection)

I have a looping http request in my activity to check for various parameters in order to know which view state/layout is needed. So I need to be able to hot swap the view state/layout when needed.

What would be the best, efficient, and clean way to implement this? As of now, what I have is every UI component is present in the XAML/AXML file. Then I programmatically set their view state to invisible/gone.

Comment: *the best, efficient, and clean way* - these are all extremely subjective criteria, therefore you will only get opinion based answers here, if any

Comment: any opinion is well appreciated since i dont have much experience yet.

Comment: we don't deal in opinions. See [ask]

Comment: im so sorry, should put this thread down? or wait for the admin to do so?

Answer (score -1):

I'd go with three different fragments for each state